# Multiple collisions spritekit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am trying to make a SpriteKit game but I cannot figure out or find a good example of multiple collision detection. 

My code:

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact{

SKPhysicsBody *firstBody;
SKPhysicsBody *secondBody;

if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
{
    firstBody = contact.bodyA;
    secondBody = contact.bodyB;
}
else
{
    firstBody = contact.bodyB;
    secondBody = contact.bodyA;
}

if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & bulletCategory) != 0) {
    [self updateScore];
    SKNode *applenode = [self childNodeWithName:(@"Apple")];
    applenode.removeFromParent;
    [self updateScore];
    SKScene *sampleScene = [[Level2 alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
    SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition flipVerticalWithDuration:0.5];
    [self.view presentScene:sampleScene transition:transition];

}
```

Worked great for one collision but I cannot seem to get it to work for multiple.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple collision?

Comment: I need my player sprite to be able to collide with a button sprite then execute some code and also have it collide with a Apple sprite then execute another bit of code.

Comment: The player collides with the button and the apple at the same time?

Comment: Ok. I have player sprite a button sprite and a door sprite. When the player hits the button I remove the door so the player can get(collide ) with the apple.

Comment: Just detect a collision/contact for the apple too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//for multiple collision you can add code like something that

- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
  {

  ```
  CGPoint contactPoint=CGPointMake(0, 0);
  //multiple collision
  if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
  {
      //first collision
      if(([contact.bodyA.node.name isEqualToString:@"hero"] && [contact.bodyB.node.name isEqualToString:@"coin"] ) || ([contact.bodyA.node.name isEqualToString:@"coin"] && [contact.bodyB.node.name isEqualToString:@"hero"]) )
      {
          if([contact.bodyA.node.name isEqualToString:@"coin"] )
          {

              [contact.bodyA.node removeFromParent];
          }
          else
          {
              [contact.bodyB.node removeFromParent];
          }

      }
      //second collision
      else if(([contact.bodyA.node.name isEqualToString:@"hero"] && [contact.bodyB.node.name isEqualToString:@"enemy"] ) || ([contact.bodyA.node.name isEqualToString:@"enemy"] && [contact.bodyB.node.name isEqualToString:@"hero"]) )
      {
          if([contact.bodyA.node.name isEqualToString:@"hero"] )
          {

              [contact.bodyA.node removeFromParent];
          }
          else
          {
              [contact.bodyB.node removeFromParent];
          }

      }
  }
  ```

  }